# trying to figure out Project euler problem 1, (get the sum of all numbers under 1000, divisible under 3, and 5

Tags: swift, xcode

I am able to print out on the screen the numbers divisible by 3, and 5 under 1000, but am unsure how I am suppose to add the sum of all the numbers! please help me get in right direction thanks! :) Only been doing swift for two days now, really enjoying it. But that being my code may not be the prettiest ;)

```
import UIKit

func sumFinder (untill n : Int) {
    print (3)
    print (5)
    var num1 = 3
    var num2 = 5

    for iteration in 0...n {
        var num3 = num1 + 3
        var num4 = num2 + 5
        print(num3)
        print(num4)

        num1 = num3
        num2 = num4

       let sum = (num1 + num2 + num3 + num4)

    }


}

sumFinder(untill:1000)
```

Comment: You have several issues.  You are printing numbers much larger than 1000, and you're printing numbers like 15 and 30 twice because they are multiples of both 3 and 5 but should only be summed once.  Declare your `sum` var before the loop with `var sum = 0` and add the numbers to it.  Try to figure out how not to count multiples of 15 twice.

Comment: Note that PE #1 asks for the sum of all the multiples of 3 **or** 5 below 1000. None of the answers given so far solves this correctly.

Comment: read the title **divisible under 3, and 5**  is and not or

Comment: @Sh_Khan: Read the problem: https://projecteuler.net/problem=1. (33165 is not the correct solution.)

Comment: the op repeats **and** in title and description anyway it's not the big deal if this is even misunderstood he can tweak it if he knows little in programming

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in one line: Create a range, filter the items with `isMultiple(of` and sum up the result with `reduce`

```
func sumFinder (until n : Int) -> Int {
    return (0...n).lazy.filter{ $0.isMultiple(of: 3) && $0.isMultiple(of: 5) }.reduce(0, +)
}

sumFinder(until: 1000) // 33165
```

However the actual challenge in [Project Euler – Problem 1](https://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=001) is

> Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 **or** 5 below 1000

In this case the result is 234168. Replace `&&` with `||`

```
func sumFinder (until n : Int) -> Int {
    return (0...n).lazy.filter{ $0.isMultiple(of: 3) || $0.isMultiple(of: 5) }.reduce(0, +)
}
```

Comment: `$0.isMultiple(of: 3) && $0.isMultiple(of: 5)` =  `$0.isMultiple(of: 15)`

Comment: @Sh_Khan Yes, I know, it's just to literally fulfill the requirements.

Comment: The question is misleading. PE #1 asks for the sum of all the multiples of 3 **or** 5 below 1000.

Comment: @MartinR You cannot prove everything 

Comment: @MartinR give it a break , you have no prove about that , make it for something that deserve , your link isn't mentioned by the op

Answer (score -1):

You can try

**Your attempt**

```
func getSum(_ toValue:Int) -> Int {
    var sum = 0
    for i in (0...toValue) {
       if i.isMultiple(of: 15) {
         sum += i
       }
     }
   return sum
}
```

For short swifty way ( **Recommended** )

```
func getSum(_ toValue:Int) -> Int { 
   return stride(from: 0, to:toValue, by: 1).filter{ $0.isMultiple(of:15)}.reduce(0,+)
}
```

**Test**

```
print(getSum(1000)) // 33165
```

---

**Side note**

An int that is multiable of 3 and 5 is multiple of there multiplication ( 15 ) so this

```
i.isMultiple(of: 3) && i.isMultiple(of: 5) = i.isMultiple(of: 15)
```